# Make UI Wait for Method Response

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am a new swift developer.  I am using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.2.

I need my UI to wait until a method has finished so I can use the result to display a balance.  I am trying to use a `dispatchGroup` for this, but it does not appear to be waiting because the value of `user?.userId` below is `nil`.  Here is my code:

```
    // Load the local user data.  Must wait until this is done to continue.
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    let user = LocalStorageService.loadCurrentUser()
    dispatchGroup.leave()

    // Display the current balance.
    // Get a reference to the Firestore database.
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    // Make sure we have a userId and then update the balance with a listener that keeps it updated.
    // Only run this part when the dispatchGroup has completed (in this case, the user is loaded).
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        if let userId = user?.userId {

            db.collection("subs").whereField("ID", isEqualTo: userId)
                .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                    // Make sure we have a document
                    guard let document = querySnapshot?.documents.first else {
                        print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }
                    // We have a document and it has data.  Use it.
                    self.balance = document.get("balance") as! Double

                    // Format the balance
                    let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
                    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
                    let balanceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: self.balance as NSNumber)
                    self.balanceLabel.setTitle(balanceString, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make the UI wait until the method called in `dispatchGroup.enter()` has completed?

Here's what's in LoadCurrentUser....

```
static func loadCurrentUser() -> User? {

    // Loads the current user in the UserDefaults if there is one

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let userId = defaults.value(forKey: Constants.LocalStorage.storedUserId) as? String
    let phoneNumber = defaults.value(forKey: Constants.LocalStorage.storedPhoneNumber) as? String
    let subscriberId = defaults.value(forKey: Constants.LocalStorage.storedDocumentId) as? String

    guard userId != nil && phoneNumber != nil && subscriberId != nil else {
        return nil
    }

    // Return the user
    let u = User(userId:userId!, phoneNumber:phoneNumber!, subscriberId: subscriberId)

    return u
}
```

Comment: You leave the dispatchgroup immediately. you have to leave it when the request is finished inside the completionblock

Comment: can you show `LocalStorageService`?

Comment: As Userdefauls is basically an singleton, you wont need a dispatchgroup or anything like that to fetch it. Your user is nil because id, phonenumber or subscriberId is nil, please put a breakpoint in `guard else` to validate

Comment: It's nil because the code is running ahead before completing the defaults.  It tries to pull them before they're done.  I was trying to make it wait until the defaults are written.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but UserDefaults is a singleton, it's not being run on another thread and is happening next to instantly. No waiting needed.

Comment: I tried using `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:` and that worked one time, but could not consistently make it work.  BTW, LocalStorageService also writes the initial UserDefaults for the user, perhaps that method is still running when I try to read?

Comment: I don't know how to tell you. Nothing before `if let userId = user?.userId {` is being run on anything else than the main thread. So the reason as to `user` is nil at that point, is that the user is actually nil in `UserDefaults` Because reading and as you suggested writing, are both run on main thread

Comment: I see what you are saying.  And indeed it is nil at the point that the code you cite is run.  But I don't know why.  If I jump to another view controller, which has the same code (I know, it should be streamlined), it reads correctly and shows the correct balance.  I presume it is because the user defaults have finished writing by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you do it correctly by setting vars inside the callback so no need for  `DispatchGroup` , but to correctly use it  then do ( notice the correct place where each line should be by numbers from 1 to 4 )

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() /// 1

let user = LocalStorageService.loadCurrentUser()

// Display the current balance.
// Get a reference to the Firestore database.
let db = Firestore.firestore()
var balance = ""
// Make sure we have a userId and then update the balance with a listener that keeps it updated.
// Only run this part when the dispatchGroup has completed (in this case, the user is loaded).

    if let userId = user?.userId {

         dispatchGroup.enter() /// 2

        db.collection("subs").whereField("ID", isEqualTo: userId)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                // Make sure we have a document
                guard let document = querySnapshot?.documents.first else {
                    print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                // We have a document and it has data.  Use it.
                self.balance = document.get("balance") as! Double 

                  dispatchGroup.leave() /// 3

        }
    }

  dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { /// 4
      //update here 
     // Format the balance
       let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
       currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency 
       let balanceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: self.balance as NSNumber)
      self.balanceLabel.setTitle(balanceString, for: .normal)
  }
```

Comment: I'm still getting `nil` in `user?.userId`.  It won't run the dispatchGroup if it's `nil` so it never pulls the balance.

Comment: may be no signed in user what's inside `LocalStorageService.loadCurrentUser()`

Comment: On successful login, I store the user info into the defaults.  This method works when the user has already logged in and is returning to the app.  But when the user logs in for the first time, and those defaults are apparently still being written the app runs ahead to this view controller and the user info is still being written I guess.

Comment: then you should make this data a remote configuration in firebase or don''t depend on user uid in that table structure as you don't have it when you open the app for the first time

Comment: Can I make the UI wait until the defaults are written and loaded into `user`?

Comment: yes that's why there is an activity indicator show it before loading and hide it inside the response

Comment: So I would use a dispatch group on the login view controller where the defaults are being written and wait until it is done to continue?

Comment: yes , note `DispatchGroup` is meant for many asynchnous operations in your case 1 request nest a function call that gets the price inside the response of the sign in directly below the lines that save the user

Comment: I am marking your answer correct because it is correct.  I don't need a dispatch group here.  I need it somewhere else when I am writing the default user values so when it gets to this point the user defaults are populated and will not return nil.

Comment: @TMLynch the `DispatchGroup` isn't needed here completely i added it to show how to use but you can get rid of all the 4 lines and put the label code inside the callback ,  it's needed when you have many asynchronous tasks that you want to know when all are done as they work concurrently at the same time , while your case is serial one request depends on the other

Comment: I finally solved the issue by using your dispatchGroup example above in the LoginViewController (the prior VC).  I make the LoginVC wait until the function that writes the user defaults has completed before instantiating the New VC that was getting a nil when retrieving the user details.  @Vollan I was not able to populate a variable in an instance of the New VC because I don't instantiate that from the Login VC.  I instantiate a TabBarController which has the NewVC as the default tab.  There's probably a way to do it, but I couldn't figure it out.  I'm very new to all this.  Thank you both.